# Is the number of tty the maximum number of simultaneous sessions?

Tags: terminal, tty, session

When running `who` I can see two "sessions" (it is the correct wording ?) from two remote servers:

```
pts/0
pts/1
```

I went to `/dev/pts` and I can see `0` `1`

Does that mean that I can have two simultaneous remote connections to the Linux host? Is it a similar concept to CISCO's vty lines?

Comment: A comment about English: “tty's number” = the number of a particular tty (“this terminal is on `/dev/pts/3`, the tty's number is 3”); “number of ttys” = the total number of ttys (“there are four entries in `/dev/pts`, the number of ttys is 4”).

Answer (score 6):

Entries are added to `/dev/pts` dynamically, so you’re not limited by the number of entries already present. The kernel uses character devices with majors from 136 to 143 (see [the kernel’s device list](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html)), so you can have up to 2048 entries (256 × (143 ‑ 136 + 1)).

LWN recently published an [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/688809/) on the topic which has a ton of details; you’ll also find relevant answers on this site: [What is stored in /dev/pts files and can we open them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93531/86440) and [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/86440) for example.

The underlying concept is known as Unix98 ptys, and appears to be similar to Cisco vtys (from what I’ve understood of the latter).