# Pseudo Terminal Error :: "mesg: cannot open /dev/pts/2: Permission denied"

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, error-handling, pseudoterminal

On my Ubuntu 20.04.5 machine, I have a Perl script running under `userA`'s account.  The script issues this command:

```
sudo su - userB -c "ssh -l userB 10.0.0.1 ls -tr /some/remote/directory"
```

(i.e., SSH to a remote host as `userB`, and then list all the files in `/some/remote/directory`)

The command works great... except that I'm seeing an error on the command line:

```
me@ubuntu1$ sudo su - userB -c "ssh -l userB 10.0.0.1 ls -tr /some/remote/directory"
mesg: cannot open /dev/pts/2: Permission denied
Welcome to 10.0.0.1!  You have logged in.
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
me@ubuntu1$
```

What is that `mesg: cannot open /dev/pts/2: Permission denied` message???

[A little Internet research](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93531/what-is-stored-in-dev-pts-files-and-can-we-open-them) reveals that:

> Entries in /dev/pts are pseudo-terminals (pty for short). Unix kernels
> have a generic notion of terminals. A terminal provides a way for
> applications to display output and to receive input through a terminal
> device.

And assuming that I'm only reading through my pseudo-terminal:

> If a program opens a terminal for reading, the input from the user is
> passed to that program. If multiple programs are reading from the same
> terminal, each character is routed independently to one of the
> programs; this is not recommended. Normally there is only a single
> program actively reading from the terminal at a given time; programs
> that try to read from their controlling terminal while they are not in
> the foreground are automatically suspended by a SIGTTIN signal.

That's interesting... but I'm still befuddled why I'm seeing `mesg: cannot open /dev/pts/2: Permission denied`.  I'm still developing my script and have run it several times; I can't remember if I noticed this error message on the first run.  Is it likely that every time my script runs, it tries to access `/dev/pts/2` every time, but my code didn't properly close the connection or something?

Or might this be related to `userA` using `userB` to run the command?  Pseudo-terminals wouldn't come into play when accessing another user account, would they?

Any insight or feedback is welcome, thank you.

Comment: can you try with `ssh -t ..........` ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot  Thanks Gilles.  So running `sudo su - userB -c "ssh -t -l userB...` didn't make a difference; the error message still appears, sadly.

Comment: Does this happen if you invoke `sudo su - userB` to become userB and then separately invoke the ssh command `ssh -l userB 10.0.0.1 'ls -tr /some/remote/directory'` ?

Comment: @SottoVoce If I manually test on the command line and break the command up into the `sudo su - userB` and then issue the `ssh` command, no, there is no error message.  I'd like to keep the command as one line in my script, if possible.  Thanks!

Comment: My question was for diagnosis.  No error from the `mesg` command was seen in the ssh to the remote server, so it's most likely coming from the local server.  Does userB have some sort of invocation of `mesg` in their home directory's `.bash_profile` or `.zprofile` file?

Comment: @SottoVoce Thanks Sotto.  When I look at `userB`'s home directory, I don't see a `.bash_profile` or `.zprofile`.  I do see `.bash_history`, `.bash_logout`, `.bashrc`, `.profile` files, tho.  None of these have a line with `mesg` in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if group assigned of that device is "tty", just add the user in that group tty (/etc/group).

Regards