# renaming pts file name using mv command: permission denied

Tags: linux, command-line

There is something I am still not getting yet.
I was playing around with `/dev/pts/0` file by changing the file permission into `720`, in order to rename that file into something different, but, still, permission is "denied".
Could someone tell me the reason for that?

Thanks a million.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is stored in /dev/pts files and can we open them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93531/what-is-stored-in-dev-pts-files-and-can-we-open-them)

Comment: Permission bits of the file itself don't come into play for renaming the file. [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/170373) describes at least some of it.