# Unable to determine your tty name on Debian Wheezy on ARM

Tags: debian, arm, pam, autologin, getty

while trying to create my Debian Wheezy image for a FriendlyARM mini210s ARM single board computer, I am bumping into this issue.

I have opened a terminal via serial `sudo screen /dev/cu.usbserial 115200` and that my current output:

```
[    3.398751] apple 0003:05AC:0220.0003: input: USB HID v1.11 Device [Apple, Inc Apple Keyboard] on usb-s5p-ehci-1.4.2/input1
INIT: version 2.88 booting
INIT: Entering runlevel: 2
INIT: Id "X1" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes

Debian GNU/Linux 7 FriendlyARM ttySAC0

FriendlyARM login: root      <======= entered root and hit return
Unable to determine your tty name.    <===== THE ISSUE

Debian GNU/Linux 7 FriendlyARM ttySAC0

FriendlyARM login: 

INIT: Id "6" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: Id "5" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: Id "4" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: Id "3" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: Id "2" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: Id "X1" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: Id "5" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: Id "2" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: Id "6" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: Id "4" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: Id "3" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
```

On the touchscreen, I have a message saying:

#### "login: PAM Failure, aborting: Critical error - immediate abort"

Can someone help me decrypt what this is tell me?

### How I created my `rootfs`

```
sudo debootstrap --arch=armel --foreign wheezy rootfs/ http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian

echo "proc /proc proc none 0 0" >> rootfs/etc/fstab
echo "mini210s-anybots"
echo "mini210s-anybots" > rootfs/etc/hostname 
mkdir -p rootfs/usr/share/man/man1/
mknod rootfs/dev/console c 5 1
mknod rootfs/dev/tty1 c 4 1
mknod dev/ttySAC0 c 204 64     <==== the serial port
```

then I created an image with `yaffs2utils` and booted on my FriendlyARM (I describe the process here, it's a bit long).

I copied the `inittab` from a functioning Debian Squeeze image, which contains these lines

```
T1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 ttySAC0      <=== terminal on serial port RS232 
X1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f root tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
2:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
3:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3
4:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty4
5:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty5
6:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty6
```

I am most certainly missing a couple of steps.

### UPDATE Added missing devices

Apparently I need to configure some devices. I inspired myself from [this post](http://hgweb.boddie.org.uk/qi-emdebian/file/tip/qi-emdebian-postsetup#l76)

```
mknod -m 0600 ./rootfs/dev/console  c 5 1
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/full     c 1 7
mknod -m 0640 ./rootfs/dev/kmem     c 1 2
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/loop0    b 7 0
mknod -m 0640 ./rootfs/dev/mem      c 1 1
mknod -m 0666 ./rootfs/dev/null     c 1 3
mknod -m 0640 ./rootfs/dev/port     c 1 4
mknod -m 0666 ./rootfs/dev/random   c 1 8
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/tty      c 5 0
mknod -m 0666 ./rootfs/dev/urandom  c 1 9
mknod -m 0666 ./rootfs/dev/zero     c 1 5

mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/tty0     c 5 0
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/tty1     c 5 1
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/tty2     c 5 2
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/tty3     c 5 3
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/tty4     c 5 4
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/tty5     c 5 5
```

... but still experiencing the issue.

now addding these

```
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram0 b 1 0
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram1 b 1 1
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram2 b 1 2
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram3 b 1 3
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram4 b 1 4
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram5 b 1 5
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram6 b 1 6
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram7 b 1 7
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram8 b 1 8
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram9 b 1 9
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram10 b 1 10
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram11 b 1 11
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram12 b 1 12
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram13 b 1 13
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram14 b 1 14
mknod -m 0660 ./rootfs/dev/ram15 b 1 15
```

My new `rootfs/dev`

```
root@ubuntu:/home/joel/debian-mini210s/rootfs/dev# ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Jan 19 17:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root    4096 Jun 22  2012 ..
crw-r--r--  1 root root   5,  1 Jan 19 14:07 console
crw-rw----  1 root root   1,  7 Jan 19 17:05 full
crw-r-----  1 root root   1,  2 Jan 19 17:05 kmem
brw-rw----  1 root root   7,  0 Jan 19 17:05 loop0
crw-r-----  1 root root   1,  1 Jan 19 17:05 mem
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,  3 Jan 19 17:05 null
crw-r-----  1 root root   1,  4 Jan 19 17:05 port
brw-rw----  1 root root   1,  0 Jan 19 17:27 ram0
brw-rw----  1 root root   1,  1 Jan 19 17:27 ram1
brw-rw----  1 root root   1, 10 Jan 19 17:27 ram10
brw-rw----  1 root root   1, 11 Jan 19 17:27 ram11
brw-rw----  1 root root   1, 12 Jan 19 17:27 ram12
brw-rw----  1 root root   1, 13 Jan 19 17:27 ram13
brw-rw----  1 root root   1, 14 Jan 19 17:27 ram14
brw-rw----  1 root root   1, 15 Jan 19 17:27 ram15
brw-rw----  1 root root   1,  2 Jan 19 17:27 ram2
brw-rw----  1 root root   1,  3 Jan 19 17:27 ram3
brw-rw----  1 root root   1,  4 Jan 19 17:27 ram4
brw-rw----  1 root root   1,  5 Jan 19 17:27 ram5
brw-rw----  1 root root   1,  6 Jan 19 17:27 ram6
brw-rw----  1 root root   1,  7 Jan 19 17:27 ram7
brw-rw----  1 root root   1,  8 Jan 19 17:27 ram8
brw-rw----  1 root root   1,  9 Jan 19 17:27 ram9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,  8 Jan 19 17:05 random
crw-rw----  1 root root   5,  0 Jan 19 17:05 tty
crw-rw----  1 root root   5,  0 Jan 19 17:07 tty0
crw-r--r--  1 root root   4,  1 Jan 19 14:47 tty1
crw-rw----  1 root root   5,  2 Jan 19 17:07 tty2
crw-rw----  1 root root   5,  3 Jan 19 17:07 tty3
crw-rw----  1 root root   5,  4 Jan 19 17:07 tty4
crw-rw----  1 root root   5,  5 Jan 19 17:07 tty5
crw-r--r--  1 root root 204, 64 Jan 19 14:11 ttySAC0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,  9 Jan 19 17:05 urandom
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,  5 Jan 19 17:05 zero
```

but still getting `Unable to determine your tty name`

### UPDATE - added `ttySAC0` to `/etc/securetty`

In `vim /etc/pam.d/login` Line:

```
auth [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=ok ignore=ignore user_unknown=bad default=die] pam_securetty.so
```

this should allo login without password, if device listed. ... but that didn't work out as I expected.

### Found on the Internet about this issue

[On AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147184/12-04-x64-server-login-failure)

[eBook on the issue](https://books.google.de/books?id=FyRhZJ3h3VQC&pg=PA518&lpg=PA518&dq=login:+PAM+Failure,+aborting:+Critical+error+-+immediate+abort&source=bl&ots=wKM_e-xt-C&sig=sIixzmbFbjskOp2JHYwQPEIYtzc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bXjKVNDYEsLtao2UgtgL&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=login%3A%20PAM%20Failure%2C%20aborting%3A%20Critical%20error%20-%20immediate%20abort&f=false)

Comment: The messages from init are because of the lines for `tty1` and so on in `inittab`. Remove them, these devices don't exist. I don't see why `/dev/ttySAC0` is partially working. Is there an initramfs in this setup? Do you run udev?

Comment: Ok I need to check and learn more about `initramfs` and `udev`. thanks for these pointers. I couldn't find any file named `initramfs`, but in the meantime I created a few missing devices. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: I think I cleared the `INIT: Id "6" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes` issues, but still getting the `Unable to determine your tty name`. See post updates

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the underlying issue is nothing to do with your tty, but rather that is a consequence of the far more important error message further down, *PAM Failure, aborting: Critical error - immediate abort*.

[This article](http://www.debianhelp.org/content/login-pam-failure-aborting-critical-error-immediate-abort) from the Debian Help site may help. (TL;DR? CR/LF on the end of lines in PAM configuration files is bad.) But without knowing what you've done with the PAM subsystem it can only be a guess.

Comment: I actually haven't done anything with it yet. I don't know how to configure it to be honest. I will be studying this next. Thanks for this pointer.

Comment: This article you pointed out didn't resolve, but looking at the PAM config is probably a good lead. thanks again

Comment: The article title is, "PAM Failure, aborting: Critical error - immediate abort" published on 2011-06-08.

Comment: Certainly, the article matches the error but the information in it didn't match the same problem. I don't even use Windows anywhere, my configuration file isn't bad. But again thanks for putting me in that direction. It was interesting reading about it.

Comment: OK. I'm looking forward to seeing the final solution. It's piqued my curiousity!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing several things in `/dev`. You were initially missing `/dev/tty`, which the kernel internally reroutes to the calling process's own terminal. The `getty` and `login` programs talk to a specific terminal (here `/dev/ttySAC0`), but after that other programs just want to communicate via whichever terminal they're running on, and they use `/dev/tty` for that. You've created it, but with the wrong permissions: `/dev/tty` needs to be accessible by all processes. So does `/dev/full`, by the way, although it's very rarely used so that probably doesn't break anything in practice.

```
chmod a+rw /dev/tty
```

(`/dev/console`, on the other hand, is correctly reserved to root. `/dev/tty` refers to the terminal that the process is running on, which can be a software terminal such as xterm, sshd, screen, etc. `/dev/console`, on the other hand, refers to a console, i.e. a physical terminal; few programs need to interact with the console as such.)

In addition, in order to use terminal emulators such as screen, you need to create [`/dev/ptmx`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79334/how-does-a-linux-terminal-work/79354#79354) and to mount [`/dev/pts`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93531/what-is-stored-in-dev-pts-files-and-can-we-open-them).

```
mknod -m 666 /dev/ptmx c 5 2
mkdir /dev/pts
```

and put the following line in `/etc/fstab` or run the equivalent `mount` command at boot time, with 5 replaced by the group ID for `tty` (check `/etc/group):

```
devpts /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0
```

That's all I see for now. I haven't tested, it's possible that something else is missing.

Comment: the `rootfs` I have, doesn't contain the `/etc/group` ... FYI I built my rootfs with this command `sudo debootstrap --arch=armel --foreign squeeze rootfs/ http://www.emdebian.org/grip/`. I will start with correcting the permissions on `tty` and `null` devices. thx