# What is the purpose of the pts directory in linux

Tags: terminal

I ran the `last` command in Linux; I got the output:

> pts/0, pts/1, pts/2, pts/3, pts/4 and pts/5

What does *pts* mean?

Comment: Hello Ahmed, and welcome to U&L! Don't be afraid to use the search bar for key words in your question -- for example, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21280/difference-between-pts-and-tty would be a good start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `pts/0` is telling you which *"pseudo terminal"* the user was logged in on. In this case it's terminal 0,1,2 etc.

A `tty` is a native terminal device, the backend is either hardware or kernel emulated.

A `pts` (*pseudo terminal device*) is a terminal device which is emulated by an other program (example: `xterm`, `screen`, or `ssh` are such programs).

Comment: Thanks Mazs,Can we get the description of that in the last command,Say like if it is pts/1 it is for ssh,pts/2 it is from winscp,pts/3 it is su.

Comment: @AhmedVagher No, absolutely not. The first pseudoterminal that's created gets the number 0, the next one gets 1 and so on.

Comment: Just worth noting that different naming/numbering schemes exist, e.g. one pty might be at /dev/ptyp0.

Comment: @AhmedVagher As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Actually "pts" stands for pseudo-terminal-slave.  The answer as given confuses tty and pty, making it less than useful.