# Explain who command output in 2nd column

Tags: who

I have 2 machine setup of rhel7 , one is in terminal mode and the other is in grahical mode , when I run '`who`' command on both the machines why do I get '`tty`' in 2nd column output for the machine in terminal mode and '`pts`' for machine in graphical mode

Comment: tty - real TTYs; pts - Pseudo-terminal stuffs

Comment: try `who -H` to see the headings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here 
[What is the purpose of the pts directory in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235882/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-pts-directory-in-linux/235884#235884)

The pts/0 is telling you which "pseudo terminal" the user was logged in on. In this case it's terminal 0,1,2 etc.
A tty is a native terminal device, the backend is either hardware or kernel emulated.
A pts (pseudo terminal device) is a terminal device which is emulated by an other program (example: xterm, screen, or ssh are such programs).
The :0 means the graphical display number, where display / screen are logical concepts of X windows system (not physical display).

Answer (score 0):

Logins that are done on a real terminal have a real terminal name in column 2 of the `who` output.

Logins that are "virtual", (e.g. by ssh or by a GUI) run under a terminal emulation in a so called "Pseudo tty" driver.

`pty` is an appreviation for pseudo tty.