# Why is the ssh utility considered a pty?

Tags: ssh, tty, console, terminology, pty

I've read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21294/258010) that `ssh` is considered a pty. Why? If I run an `ssh` command in my console (say, in a Debian server), where comes the "pty" aspect of `ssh` here? For me, it's like I'm using any other utility like `cat` or `sed`, so where comes the "pty" aspect here?

In `screen` or `tmux` it would seem more plausible to use this term (even though I think it's quite uncommon and these should be named "multiplexers").

Comment: You heard wrong. `ssh` is not a pseudoterminal. To learn what a pseudoterminal (pty) is you may begin by reading the manual page of [`pty - pseudoterminal interfaces`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/pty.7.html). What `sshd` (the server side of `ssh`) does is create a pty and run a shell in it.

Comment: Actually, the master side and the slave side of a pty **must** be be on the same machine. When you use ssh interactively, you have the following situation. On the *local* machine your are running a terminal emulator, such as PuTTY or Xterm. The terminal emulator has the master side of a pty, with the slave side connected to the `ssh` process. The `ssh` process talks over the network  with the `sshd` daemon on the *remote* machine. On the *remote* machine, the `sshd` daemon has the master side of a pty, with the slave side connected to the shell or whatever program you are running.

Comment: Thank you so much AlexP. This is a great, super clear and didactic explanation for me. I really appreciate your help. I wouldn't allow myself using it into an answer because I think you should just copy it into an answer of yours (with a minor edit) and I will gladly thumb up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ssh` is the *client* and communicates with your `tty` via your *tty's standard output* on the local machine. On the remote machine, a `pty` is created by [sshd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd) when you login.

`sshd` then executes your `shell`, connecting it to its `pty` so that instead of showing up on the remote machine information is forwarded through `ssh` to the local machine.

The `shell` connects to the `pty` just like it would a `tty` used locally but the information sent to the `pty` is not printed to the local screen but is directed to `sshd` then sends it to the connected `ssh` *client* which makes `sshd` a *pseudo-terminal*.

Comment: Dear jdwolf. I understood all of the answer besides this `The shell connects just like any other tty`. Will you please rephrase it or give a small explanation to this sentence? In great plea.

Comment: @Arcticooling How's that?

Comment: You meant just `like it would be`? If so it is more understandable.

Comment: @Arcticooling yes

Comment: @jdwolf is there a graphical representation of this interaction from client/server and use of components in the web?